# How to set size and image of JButton?

Tags: java, swing, size

Sorry if this is a really stupid question but I can't figure out how to set the size of a JButton. I'm trying to create a custom JButton class which can be called from anywhere with custom text to make things easier. I am also trying to set a background image which doesn't appear to be working either.
I have tried using this.setSize(1000, 1000) (surely this should work) but this does nothing at all.

Here is my code:

```
package menu;

import javax.swing.*;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class Button extends JButton
{

    public Button(String name)
    {
        ImageIcon background = new ImageIcon("/assets/buttons/menu.png"); //Is this how you set a background image for a button?
        this.setText(name);
        this.setIcon(background);
        this.setLayout(null); //This hasn't made a difference
        this.setSize(300, 80); //This does nothing
    }
}
```

Comment: With regards to the size issue, what layout manager are you using?

Comment: I don't know of any Swing component that will automatically resize the associated image.  You're going to have to provide this functionality yourself

Comment: Erm...None. That's all my code for it there.

Comment: can you post the code were you add the button to the "screen" jframe thats were you should add this.setLayout(null);

Comment: Everything is working now. Except the image isn't loading. I will look into that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

```
import javax.swing.JButton;


public class replaceButton **extends JButton**
{
    public replaceButton(String name)
    {
         this.setText(name);
         ImageIcon background = new ImageIcon("/assets/buttons/menu.png");
         this.setIcon(background);
         this.setSize(1000,1000);
    }
}
```

by extending JButton you give it the properties of a button.

make sure you dont have any layout by adding this to the JFrame

```
this.setLayout(null);
```

else the button will be adjusted to the layout

see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/border.html

Comment: Nothing. The button is still too small and I don't think the image is even loading...

Comment: I just want to resize the button, which is remaining the same. The default text doesn't even fit.

Comment: Where do you add the button by the way?

Comment: It is a button. I've done all of that. I will update my post with all the code in the class for you if it helps.

Comment: I hope it will help, it is working on my computer maybey somehting to do with layout..

Comment: Forgot to put the setLayout in the frame. I put it in the button. Whoops XD

Comment: `null` layout is not advisable, nor is `setSize`, if you MUST supply a size of a component, you should override the `getPreferredSize` of the component and use an appropriate layout manager...